# can you help me identify the word xiamen

Tags: mandarin

In a mandarin course, before the dialogs they always say "qing ting ... Xiamen de duihua".   I have never been able to find out what the word "xiamen" means.   The rest of it means "please listen... ____ the dialog".   I know Xiamen is a city near Shenzhen but that cannot be it!   Thank you ... 谢谢

Comment: Thank you Tang Ho!! much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

请听 /qǐng tīng/ (please listen)

下面的 /xiàmiàn de/ (below/ the following)

对话 /duìhuà/ (conversation)

> 请听下面的对话  Qǐng tīng xiàmiàn de duìhuà

> Please listen to the following conversation